# Combine 2 Queries with different number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a query that connects to a `wordpress db` and returns some `posts`.

In order to get the `image` for each of these posts i run another query inside a `php foreach loop`

The problem is that running the second query inside the `foreach loop` is extremely slow and i need another way to merge these 2 `queries` into 1.

**The first query**

```
SELECT pm. * , p.*
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID
WHERE pm.meta_key = 'accommodation_location_post_id'
AND pm.meta_value
IN (   
SELECT pi.ID
FROM wp_posts pi
WHERE pi.post_title LIKE '%Cyprus%')
```

Based on the returned **post ids**, i need for each of these ids
the featured image.

This query does this job, but only for **1 id** only.

**The second query**

```
SELECT wp_posts.guid 
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.ID = 
(Select wp_postmeta.meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 
'_thumbnail_id' AND wp_postmeta.post_id = 'The id of each post')
```

I need a query to return **all the posts** alongside with its images.

Comment: utilize normalization for doing it.

Comment: what field from 1-st query is used for 'The id of each post'?

Comment: The post id -> wp_posts.ID

Comment: It's something strange with queries. In the 2-nd query you get `wp_posts.guid`. Is it image? In 1-st query you get `guid` too (`p.*`).

Comment: It's the only way to get these data from the Wordpress db. These queries are both work. But I need them as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't understand your data structure, but try this query

```
select
    t1.*, t2.guid
from (
    SELECT pm. * , p.*
    FROM wp_posts p
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    WHERE pm.meta_key = 'accommodation_location_post_id'
AND pm.meta_value IN (
    SELECT pi.ID
        FROM wp_posts pi
        WHERE pi.post_title LIKE '%Cyprus%'
    )
) t1
left join (
    select
        p2.guid, pm2.post_id
    from
        wp_posts p2
        join wp_postmeta pm2 on
            pm2.meta_value = p2.ID
            and pm2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
) t2 on t2.post_id = t1.ID
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you very much! Can you explain to me a little bit how this query works?

Comment: `t1` is first query, `t2` is modified second query from question. These queries are joined by condition `t2.post_id = t1.ID`, `t2.post_id` is `wp_postmeta.post_id` from 2-nd query, `t1.ID` is `wp_posts.ID` from 1-st query.